# Unable to set <UIImage:0x283942880 anonymous {1080, 1080} renderingMode=automatic> to UIImageView XCode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have built an app which fetches contacts from phonebook and saves their name and photo. To save the photo I've used the following code

```
if let imageData = contact.thumbnailImageData {
                            
     imageStr = String(describing: UIImage(data: imageData)!)
                            
} else {
                        
     imageStr = "null"
}
```

and when I print imageStr using `print("IMGSTR: \(imageStr)")` I get the following output

```
IMSTR: <UIImage:0x283942880 anonymous {1080, 1080} renderingMode=automatic>
```

Now I'm stuck on how to set this string to the UIImageView, I tried

```
imageview.image = UIImage(named: imageStr)
```

but it shows nothing

Could someone please help me in how to set the string `<UIImage:0x283942880 anonymous {1080, 1080} renderingMode=automatic>` to `UIImageView`?

Comment: I don’t think `String(describing: UIImage(data: imageData)!)` does what you think it does. What are you expecting the value of the string to be from this?

Comment: I want to save "contact.thumbnailImageData" as string in an array using UserDefaults and later retrieve it and set to my UIImageView

Comment: How to set it to imageview?

Comment: I'm getting this value ```<UIImage:0x283942880 anonymous {1080, 1080} renderingMode=automatic>``` from ```String(describing: UIImage(data: imageData)!)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert it to a String. `UserDefaults` supports `Data` objects. Store it as `Data` and when setting it to a `UIImageView` use  `let image = UIImage(data : imageData)`

If you want to convert an instance of `Data` to `String`, you should use the `String(decoding:as:)` initializer, like this.(eg : `let str = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)`).

Comment: Great solution! This really helped